# Selectively include headers in Qt using preprocessors

Tags: qt, include, preprocessor

I am trying to include windows specific headers on a cross-platform project in the following way.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include "qt_windows.h"
#include "Shellapi.h"
#endif
```

For some reasons, the files are not included properly.

**Note:** I am using mingw-gcc compiler.

Comment: What sort of error do you get? Is Q_OS_WIN defined?

Comment: In complaints about the methods defined in Shellapi.h don't exist. I assume Q_OS_WIN is defined by Qt.

Comment: You should include any qt header  file(for example <QtGlobal>) befofe use `Q_OS_WIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is defined. It should be `Q_OS_WIN32` or `Q_WS_WIN`. See [Qt Global](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtglobal.html).

```
#include <QtGlobal>

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
#include "qt_windows.h"
#include "Shellapi.h"
#endif
```